# H2O xgboost mojo prediction warnings

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to produce a prediction from new data using a XGBoost `mojo` object in H2O. When I predict though, various messages, giving warnings, get displayed

```
Feb 26, 2019 12:43:47 PM ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.NativeLibrary extractAndLoad
WARNING: Cannot load library from path lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so
Feb 26, 2019 12:43:47 PM ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.NativeLibrary extractAndLoad
WARNING: Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_gpu.so
Feb 26, 2019 12:43:47 PM ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.NativeLibrary doLoad
WARNING: Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Feb 26, 2019 12:43:47 PM ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.NativeLibraryLoaderChain loadNativeLibs
INFO: Cannot load library: xgboost4j_gpu (lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so)
Feb 26, 2019 12:43:47 PM ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.NativeLibrary extractAndLoad
INFO: Loaded library from lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_omp.so (/tmp/libxgboost4j_omp7945713229272382570.so)

       predict          setosa      versicolor       virginica
1       setosa 0.9961976408958 0.0030118888244 0.0007904054946
2       setosa 0.9963765740395 0.0026796606835 0.0009437160916
3       setosa 0.9963235855103 0.0028859297745 0.0007905053790
4       setosa 0.9963260293007 0.0028859369922 0.0007880008779
5       setosa 0.9961976408958 0.0030118888244 0.0007904054946
```

Here is a basic reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(h2o)

h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = '5g') # All available cores

data(iris)
iris.hex <- as.h2o(iris, destination_frame = "iris.hex")

iris.gbm <- h2o.xgboost(y = 5, x = 1:4, training_frame = iris.hex, ntrees = 100,
                        max_depth = 3,
                        learn_rate = 0.2,
                        distribution= "AUTO")

h2o.download_mojo(iris.gbm, "Mojo_models/", get_genmodel_jar = T)
h2o.shutdown()
```

Warning messages occurs once I try and perform the predictions

```
h2o.mojo_predict_df(iris, mojo_zip_path = "Mojo_models/XGBoost_model_R_1551184956713_1.zip", genmodel_jar_path = "Mojo_models/h2o-genmodel.jar", 
                    java_option =  '-Xmx1g -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m')
```

Is this something I should be worried about? If not, why are the messages occurring and can I suppress them somehow?

*Relevant session info:*

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.0

other attached packages:
 [1] h2o_3.22.1.1    forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.8     purrr_0.3.0     readr_1.2.1     tidyr_0.8.2     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_3.1.0   tidyverse_1.2.1
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error. I had to change `get_genmodel_jar` to `TRUE` and change the name of the model to `h2o-genmodel.jar`. But otherwise, worked perfectly. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the latest R 3.5.2, but the same version of h2o.

Comment: Thanks, changed the post to reflect the edits. Updated `xgboost`, `h2o` and `R`. Still getting the warnings. It still produces predictions, which is the strange part

Comment: Well, I have no idea what may be causing it (Ubuntu libraries?), but you can always suppress the warnings wrapping the predict function call with a `suppressWarnings()`.

Answer (score 0):

H2O is trying to and failing to load the GPU version XGBoost. It then loads the CPU version. This is not something to be worried about unless you think the GPU version should be loading.